# gallery with next and prev function

Tags: php

I'm working on an image gallery as my first real project as of learning php.. The problem I'm not able to get around somehow is using the "previous" button. My "next" function grabs the next 6 images from the folder and posts them to the page, my prev function does this in reverse.. but that's incorrect, can you help? oh, and this code is sloppy beginner code so i'm happy for tips :)

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(session_id() == '') {
 $_SESSION["count"] = 0;
}

function PostHTML($id, $file) {
    if($id==0) {
           echo "<div class=\"item\"><div class=\"well\"><img 
           class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"$file\" alt=\"\"><p>blahblahblah xxxxxx</p></div></div>";
    }else{
           echo "<div class=\"item\"><div class=\"well\"><video autoplay 
           loop class=\"img-responsive\"><source src=\"$file\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></div></div>";
    }
}

function next_img() {

   $dir = "images/src/*.*"; 

   $files = array();
   $start = $_SESSION["count"];
   $end = $_SESSION["count"]+6;

   $y=0;
       foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
          $files[$y] = $file;
          $y++;
       }

for($i=$start; $i < $end; $i++){
   if(pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=="jpg") { 
     PostHTML(0,$files[$i]); 
   } else { 
     PostHTML(1,$files[$i]); }
}


$_SESSION["count"]+=6;


}

function prev_img() {
   $dir = "images/src/*.*"; 

   $files = array();
   $start = $_SESSION["count"]-1; 
   $end = $_SESSION["count"]-6;

   $y=0;
   foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
        $files[$y] = $file; //100 files
        $y++;  
    }

   for ($i = $start; $i > $end; $i--) {
        if(pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=="jpg") { 
         PostHTML(0,$files[$i]); 
       } else { 
         PostHTML(1,$files[$i]); 
       }   
   }
   $_SESSION["count"]-=6;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i were to do something like this I might create a File Controller class to manage all the file operations i might need.

```
<?php




class FileController
{

    private $_dir = "DIR";
    private $files;
    private $current;

    function__construct()
    {

        $current = 0;

        $files = scandir($_dir); // scans the dir to get a list of file names
        if(!$files) echo "Failed To Load Files"; // failed to load files
        else 
        {
            $this->file = $files; // objects propery contains all file names in array;
        }

    }


    function PostHTML($fileName) {


        $src = $this->_dir + "/" + $fileName;

        if(!$fileName)
        {
                return "<div class=\"item\"><div class=\"well\"><img 
           class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"$src\" alt=\"\"><p>blahblahblah xxxxxx</p></div></div>";
        }
        else
        {

            return "<div class=\"item\"><div class=\"well\"><video autoplay 
           loop class=\"img-responsive\"><source src=\"$src\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></div></div>";
        }
}




    function nextImg()
    {

        $current = $this->getCurrent();
        $end = $current + 6;
        $this->setCurrent($end);
        $files = $this->files;

        $html = "";
        for($i = $current; $i<= $end; $i++)
        {
            $html += postHtml($files[$i]);
        }

        echo $html;


    }


    function prevImg()
    {

        $current = $this->getCurrent();
        $end = $current - 6;
        $this->setCurrent($end);
        $files = $this->files;

        $html = "";
        for($i = $current; $i>= $end; $i--)
        {
            $html += postHtml($files[$i]);
        }

        echo $html;



    }

    function getCurrent()
    {
        return $_SESSION['current'];

    }

    function setCurrent($current)
    {
            $_SESSION['current'] = $current;

    }






}


?>
```

Comment: that actually caused more problems than my original post :p thanks anyway though.